# Adding corporate banner/logo to video playlist or Windows screen output

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, watermark, overlay

We have a repository of video animations of varying codecs/resolutions/frame-rates/etc that are currently playing on rotation in VLC player as a corporate display.  I've been asked to add a corporate banner or logo to this, so that the videos play underneath the banner or so that the logo is embedded prominently.  VLC's facility to add a logo (Tools/Effects and Filters/Overlay tab) does this but sizes logo relative to the video, so the logo scales from tiny to dominating the screen for different videos.

I know there are ways to add logos to videos using for example FFmpeg, but I'm reluctant to process all these videos for that purpose (cost/benefit..) and as it'll reduce quality.

I'd be very grateful for advice on a way to add a banner/logo in a more seamless professional way to a playlist, perhaps using a layer-based approach where you can specify a banner frame above the video frame.  Or alternatively is there a way to control Windows screen output in this way?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify: You're more interested in just overlaying a watermark in a(ny) video player over any video, and _not_ actually embedding the overlay in the video files themselves?  Are you playing these videos full screen all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/expression/cc460712.aspx) is a tutorial to actually change the video.

[Here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/screenwatermark/) is a program that overlays a watermark to Windows itself.

As about overlay an image through a media player, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442902/how-to-overlay-or-watermark-a-picture-in-windows-media-player) is a question regarding it, but it appears to involve code and other stuff that i don't understand.

Good Luck

Comment: Awesome thanks Nuno.  Screen Watermark is exactly what I had in mind - very neat little app!

Comment: Need one for OSX now! Any suggestions Nuno?

Comment: I found [this app](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/42614/videomark) that adds watermarks to videos, and if you change the opacity to 100%, you should get a overlayed logo; and I also found [this blog post](http://chauvet.over-blog.com/2014/01/3-ways-to-add-watermark-to-video-files-on-mac.html) about adding watermarks on mac. Hope it helps.